# Регулярное выражение для preg_replace (Изменение HTML строки)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как составить регулярное выражение для preg_replace, чтобы при сохранении ссылки типа

```
<img src="img/image.jpg" title="desc" alt="titles" widht="200" height="100" />
```

ссылка модифицировалась в

```
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <img itemprop="url" itemprop="image" class="class" title="desc" src="img/image.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="100" />
  <meta itemprop="width" content="200">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="100">
</span>
```

забыл уточнить, изображения содержаться в тексте, и нужно вернуть строку с текстом

Answer (score 1):

Я бы разбил по элементам, а не писал бы одной регуляркой, если конечно нужно то могу написать и одной, но в таком случае возникнут сложности при внесении правок или же отказе кода.

данный пример можете протестировать на http://phptester.net/

```
<?php 
$str = '<img src="img/image.jpg" title="desc" alt="titles" width="200" height="100" />';
$src = preg_replace('/.*src="(.*?)".*$/','$1',$str);
$title = preg_replace('/.*title="(.*?)".*$/','$1',$str);
$alt = preg_replace('/.*alt="(.*?)".*$/','$1',$str);
$width = preg_replace('/.*width="(.*?)".*$/','$1',$str);
$height = preg_replace('/.*height="(.*?)".*$/','$1',$str);
echo '<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<img itemprop="url" itemprop="image" class="class" title="'.$title.'" src="'.$src.'" alt="'.$alt.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" />
<meta itemprop="width" content="'.$width.'">
<meta itemprop="height" content="'.$height.'"></span>';
```

Comment: Забыл уточнить, изображение содержиться в тексте, и нужно вернуть строку обратно

Comment: И если несколько изображений в тексте?

Comment: тогда нужно описывать одной регуляркой с глобальной заменой, но в таком случае нужно что-бы все свойства img шли в одинаковом порядке, иначе регулярка вылетит

Answer (score 1):

А я бы предпочёл не использовать регулярки в данном случае. Можно получить отдельно все аттрибуты:

```
$s = '<img src="img/image.jpg" title="desc" alt="titles" widht="200" height="100" />';
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($s);
$elements = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('img');
$img = $elements->item(0);

$title = $img->getAttribute('title');
$width = $img->getAttribute('width');
$height = $img->getAttribute('height');
$src = $img->getAttribute('src');
```

И затем красиво их вставить:

```
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<img itemprop="url" itemprop="image" class="class" title="<?=$title?>" src="<?=$src?>" alt="" width="<?=$width?>" height="<?=$height?>" />
<meta itemprop="width" content="<?=$width?>">
<meta itemprop="height" content="<?=$height?>">
</span>
```